# What is the difference between [Read Report & Get Input Report] , [Write Report & Set Output Report] in Windows HID drivers?

Tags: windows, driver, hid

I am new to HID devices. I am writing a HID driver in windows (similar to [vhidmini2](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/hid/vhidmini2)). I am a bit confused about [APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/introduction-to-hid-concepts#data-movement) used for data movement between the application and the selected device.

What is the difference between:

- [`IOCTL_HID_READ_REPORT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidport/ni-hidport-ioctl_hid_read_report) and [`IOCTL_HID_GET_INPUT_REPORT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidclass/ni-hidclass-ioctl_hid_get_input_report)/[`IOCTL_UMDF_HID_GET_INPUT_REPORT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidport/ni-hidport-ioctl_umdf_hid_get_input_report)
- [`IOCTL_HID_WRITE_REPORT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidport/ni-hidport-ioctl_hid_write_report) and [`IOCTL_HID_SET_OUTPUT_REPORT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidclass/ni-hidclass-ioctl_hid_set_output_report)/[`IOCTL_UMDF_HID_SET_OUTPUT_REPORT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidport/ni-hidport-ioctl_umdf_hid_set_output_report)
- [`ReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) and [`HidD_GetInputReport`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_getinputreport)
- [`WriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) and [`HidD_SetOutputReport`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_setoutputreport)

By difference I mean I don't understand when to use which one? As to me, I think all the pairs do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

`HidD_GetInputReport` becomes `IOCTL_HID_GET_INPUT_REPORT`.

`ReadFile` becomes `IOCTL_HID_READ_REPORT`.

`HidD_SetOutputReport` becomes `IOCTL_HID_SET_OUTPUT_REPORT`.

`WriteFile` becomes `IOCTL_HID_WRITE_REPORT`.

`ReadFile` asks for whatever report happens to come up next.  `HidD_GetInputReport` asks for one specific report.  `WriteFile` and `HidD_SetOutputReport` are pretty much identical.